# Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have problem, although i checked primary key does not exist in the database. Additional information:

> Additional information: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK_Yeucaukhachhang'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.Yeucaukhachhang'. The duplicate key value is (MH01123123).

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(sqlCnt))
{
   for (int i = 0; i < metroGrid2.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO
      Yeucaukhachhang(MaKH,MaHang,TenHang,DonViTinh,Dongia,
      SoLuong,Duyet) values('"+ makh.Text+"','"+
      metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["mahang"].Value +
      "','"+metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["tenhang"].Value+"', '"+ 
      metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["donvitinh"].Value+"', '"+ 
      metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["dongia"].Value+"', '"+ 
      metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["soluong"].Value+"', 'N')", sqlCon);
      SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DanhMucKhachHang(MaKhachHang,TenKhachHang,DiaChiKhachHang,SDTKhachHang,CMD,masothue,thanhtoan,nganhang,taikhoannganhang,ngaythang,MaHang,TenHang,DonViTinh,Dongia,SoLuong,Duyet) VALUES(@MaKhachHang,@TenKhachHang,@DiaChiKhachHang,@SDTKhachHang,@CMD,@masothue,@thanhtoan,@nganhang,@taikhoannganhang,@ngaythang)", sqlCon);
                 cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaKhachHang", makh.Text);
                 cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TenKhachHang", namekh.Text);
                 cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DiaChiKhachHang", address.Text);
                 cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDTKhachHang", phone.Text);
                 cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CMD", idkh.Text);
                 cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@masothue", idthue.Text);
                 cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@thanhtoan", deliver.Text);
                 cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nganhang", bank.Text);
                 cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@taikhoannganhang", idacc.Text);
                 cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ngaythang", this.datekh.Value);

                 sqlCon.Open();
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 sqlCon.Close();
                 MessageBox.Show("Thêm thành công, đa chuyển qua xác nhận yêu cầu");
                 LTQL.Home.Home cort = new LTQL.Home.Home();
                 cort.Show();
                 this.Hide();
             }
```

Comment: 1. Database name checked is correct.
2. Write sql delete makh=MH01123123 and try again.

Comment: Why do you use a parametrized query for `cmd1` but not for `cmd`?

Comment: please post your table structure for Yeucaukhachhang

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for us to tell whether you really have a key violation or not but I have never seen SQL make that error incorrectly.

However, I can at least give you some pointers in trying to track down the error.

First, I would recommend you rewrite your code to build your command something like this:

```
string szCommand = "INSERT INTO Yeucaukhachhang(MaKH,MaHang,TenHang,DonViTinh,Dongia,
            SoLuong,Duyet)";
szCommand += string.Format("values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')",
makh.Text, metroGrid2.rows[i].cells["mahang"].Value, 
metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["tenhang"].Value,
metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["donvitinh"].Value, 
metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["dongia"].Value, 
metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["soluong"].Value);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(szCommand,sqlCon);
```

In case you are not familiar with string.format, the thing to remember is that the numbers inside the {} refer to the parameters after the closing"

This eliminates the necessity to double-check that you have all your 's and "s in exactly the right places and orders and makes your code much easier to read when you go back to it later.

Then, if you still have a problem, just write szCommand to a text file someplace:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\log.txt", true))
{
    sw.WriteLine(szCommand);
    sw.Close();
}
```

This will show you exactly what is getting passed to your command object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks you so much, i will test accord instruction of you